# Error:(34) error: resource array/preloaded_fonts not found

Tags: android

I imported a font and then decided against it, I deleted it from my files using safe usage and nothing came up, so I deleted it.

All of a sudden I am unable to build my project and I get the error mentioned.

I try to remove

```
<meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

But this reappears after trying to build the project again. I have removed all references that I believed to be linked to this error but clearly, I am missing something.

[image]

Comment: Silly question, have you deleted it from src folder and edited manifest in the same folder?

Comment: @exe you were right, I was a bit clumsy and must have gone into the wrong folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a hint at the top of editor window:

> Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited

Edit manifest in the src folder, not in build folder. Alternatively you can find manifest in the app/manifests in the Project pane on the left.

Comment: Whoops, what a silly mistake on my part, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you create new Font without import **.ttf** file the system will automatically create *meta-data* tag in Manifest and **preloaded_fonts.xml** in values package

1. Mistake ⛔

   Delete preloaded_fonts.xml
2. Solution ✅

   Remove the  from AndroidManifest.xml
3. Overview ️

   3.1 Create new font + output
   [image]
   3.2 Fix the problem

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

I have added the preloaded_fonts.xml in value folder.. the error has gone[image]

Comment: OP explicitly wants to get rid of the fonts file, so it looks like this is maybe  an answer to another question